# Weird Expanding of TDs In Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I'm developing a grid-based display a bit like Windows 8 Metro here: http://tuxnet.co.uk/squares/ but in chrome, while it works initially, if one expands and shrinks the window repeatedly everything slowly and weirdly grows out of proportion and distorts. I have no idea why this would happen.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not encountering anything like that in FF 30.0

Comment: i had a similar "growing" on elements with `display:table-cell` some chrome versions ago. might be an webkit bug. check if it works in canary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of your height in your CSS for the squares table:

```
#squares {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    /* height: 100%; */
}
```

When dealing with web pages, height can be something tricky to calculate, since there is no strict "100%" height of a webpage. It will grow dynamically. This can cause issues when resizing as stuff is recalculated.

The alternative would be to specify a pixel height for the table instead of a percentage.

Note that in something like a Chrome App window, which has a fixed size, you won't see this issue.

Comment: Problem is that if I remove that then the sizes of the cells seem to break, a cell of rowspan 2 is no longer twice the height of a cell of rowspan 1.

Comment: @FreddyTuxworth Looking through your HTML, you've got a lot of embedded tables, to the point of excess. I know from experience that using tables for layout management can cause all sorts of nightmares. If it's important to get the resizing working, you should consider using something else that was designed for this, such as flexbox